# Is it safe to replace a switch with a dimmer on halogen spots?

Tags: electrical, lighting, switch, halogen

I live in Europe (so we're on 220V), and in the house we've got two halogen spots (on a transformer) on a plain switch.

Is it safe to replace the switch with a dimmer (like [these](http://www.niko.eu/nlbe/niko/producten/dimmers/subcategory/inbouwdimmers/))? Do the transformer and/or halogen spots need to be of a type that supports this? If so how can I tell if the are already or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, my lack of Dutch comprehension prevents me from giving a definitive statement on your situation (do you have an English translation for those switches?).  That said, I live in England and all of the halogens (with their transformers) in my flat are on dimmer switches, so it is absolutely possible to have dimmer switches on your lights.

However, you are going to have to make sure that the transformers that are currently installed in your house will work with a dimmer switch (it is possible that yours will not) by checking the manual or looking it up on the internet.

And definitely take care when working with your electrical system.  If you at all feel uncertain or uncomfortable, it may be worth the peace of mind to talk to or hire a professional.

Comment: should have looked better, there's info there indeed which one works with ring-coil-transformers and with other types